# Are all Linux applications run over shell?

Tags: linux, shell

For example when i run gui text editor and input simple text. Is this the way to have the hardware done this; **gui text editor > shell > kernel**?

The main question I want to ask is when we perform any operation on the system, this process  always transferred over the shell to the kernel ?

**What confused me was the diagram below.**

[image]

According to this diagram, whether the user uses a shell directly or runs any tool, all processes always seem to transfer over the shell to the kernel.

Or is the shell just a tool, just like other tools? So the shell's task is to give commands and manage the system? The sharpest question is, can the linux system and other tools in it, especially gui-based tools, continue to be used without shell?

What exactly is the shell and what importance in the linux system?

Comment: Where is this diagram from?

Comment: Thank you your answer @muru The diagram I found is in different places on the internet, but no one is an official source. I think the diagram here is more correct; https://bash.cyberciti.biz/uploads/bashwiki/3/38/Rela.gif

Comment: No, not all programs are launched by the shell. The shell is just a convenient way to interact with the computer (command line), but if you only use GUI tools, the shell won't even enter the picture.